# Replace characters in a string using two arrays

Tags: ruby, text, replace

I'd like to use two arrays to change characters in a string. The first array would have the original characters, the second would have the replacement characters.

```
original = ["a", "b", "c"]
replacements = ["x", "y", "z"]
text = "a xx b xx c"
# New string should be "x xx y xx z"
```

Is there an easy way to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr) to do the replacements, and [`Array#join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) to turn your arrays into strings, which is what `String#tr` expects as arguments.

```
new_text = text.tr(original.join, replacements.join)
```

[rubyFiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/3316a).

Comment: Hi @alex! i think it is good in his case. But in this case: `text = "[A] and [B]"`, `original = ["[A]", "[B]", "[C]", "[D]", "[Aa]"]`, `replacements = ["[B]", "[C]", "[D]", "[E]", "[Bb]"]` How can you replace the `text` to `"[B] and [C]"`

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the `String#tr` method http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr

Answer (score 0):

```
original = ["/", ".", ",", "|"]
replacements = ["_", "_", "_", "__"]

i = 0
original.each do |char|
  text.scan(char).size.times do
    text.sub!(char, replacements[i])
  end
  i = i+1
end
```